# How to copy dynamic xml node without namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Below xml has a dynamic element at any instance. But for this instance, the field which I want to make copy is 'getClassName' without including the names instance 'ser'. FYI I'm using xml 1.0 and XSLT for transformation.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://sample.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:getClassNames>
            <credential>
                <appUserID>d</appUserID>
                <clientName>ECSDEVTEAM</clientName>
                <repoName>HWY</repoName>
            </credential>
        </ser:getClassNames>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

sample output

```
<OperationName>getClassName</OperationName>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to **copy** a node, it will be copied as is - including its namespace and (in XSLT 1.0) all namespace nodes that are in scope.

Comment: In your input the local name of the element is `getClassNames`, so why does the output have the singular `getClassName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope ">
    <OperationName>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(soapenv:Body/*)"/>
    </OperationName>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your input will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationName>getClassNames</OperationName>
```

Comment: Thank you Mickael! That's all I need. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I was trying to implement this on DataPower Xi52, but for some unknown reasons it doesn't work.